# Best swing's layout solution in java

Tags: java, swing, layout

i'm trying to reproduce a mail client like osx lion's client. 
So i've to do something like:

[image: osx lion's client mail]

I don't know what is the best solution of layout to do that.. can someone give me some suggest? thanks!!!

Comment: i tried grouplayout but it's not very good..

Comment: this question is way too vague...

Comment: @ControlAltDel i know.. but i'm using windowsbuilder and i think that it not contains all layout.. years ago i used anchor layout ( jigloo )

Comment: If you're not sure on the basics, then code it by hand until you understand the various layouts and what they do - this will make your life much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution would be to use a **number of different layouts and components**, nested within each other until you have built up the overall layout you are looking for. Typically you would use JPanels for each of the nested areas, and perhaps a JSplitPane for the resizable window areas.

You'll may find you need to write (or find in a 3rd party library library) a number of **custom components** for specific features.

At a guess, you could do most of the mail client layout with a combination of [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) and [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). But you might also want to consider [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/), which is a great general purpose layout manager that is very flexible.

If you haven't done so alredy, you should do the [excellent Java Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

P.S. [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) is a great tool for quickly prototyping, but for more complex GUI designs like this I think you are ultimately better hand coding them.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) JSplitPane is what i need to separate contents. Is possible to give an initialization dimension in width of the jsplitpane? ( for example: give to the left component 30% of screen size for width ).

Comment: You should be able to use JSplitPane.setDividerLocation(...)

Answer (score 1):

Overall for that screenshot, a horizontal box layout might be what you're after (laying out the components from left to right to fill the space.)

You may well need to nest other layouts inside that though, as you would with most reasonably sized UIs.

Comment: with horizontal box layout is possible to resize every coloumn with mouse?

Comment: @user1190704 That's not really what a layout is for - perhaps you're after a JSplitPane? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html

Answer (score 1):

This is something you'd use JSplitPane for.  If you don't want the user to be able to resize the division between left and right you'd use BorderLayout where the left would go work like:

```
panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
panel.add( new LeftPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST );
panel.add( new CentralPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

That way the LeftPanel would be sized according its preferred width, and the center would be given the remaining width and height so it would resize itself as the user grew and shrank the window, but he left panel would be fixed width and grow and shrink in the height.

If you're just wondering about general purpose layout TableLayout is by far the simplest vs most flexible.  Not many layout problems can't be conquered using it, and its easy to understand (as opposed to SpringLayout, GroupedLayout, etc) and far less code and more robust than GridBagLayout.

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/

But for the problem you describe I don't think you have to use it.